# Kafka High Level Consumer - More partitions than threads

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am facing some issue with Kafka Java consumer API.

I have 5 partitions in a topic and all the messages are there in the partition 5. Now, trying to create a High Level Consumer with 4 threads. Looks like, since the message is in the partition 5, i am not able to consume message if the thread counts are less than 5. I am able to consume messages if the thread counts are 5.

But the document says,

> if you have more partitions than you have threads, some threads will
>   receive data from multiple partitions

It doesn't work this way. Am i missing any configuration?

Code :-

```
    public KafkaConsumerGroup(final MessagingApplicationContext messaingCtx, final MessageProcessor msgProcessor) {

            consumer = kafka.consumer.Consumer.createJavaConsumerConnector(createConsumerConfig());
            this.topic = messaingCtx.getKafkaConfig().getString(TOPIC_STR);

            this.readerService = messaingCtx.getRederService();
            this.msgProcessor = msgProcessor;
        }


    public void run(final int threadsCount) {
            final Map<String, Integer> topicsMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
            topicsMap.put(topic, threadsCount);
            final Map<String, List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>>> consumerMap = consumer.createMessageStreams(topicsMap);
            final List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>> streams = consumerMap.get(topic);


            int threadNumber = 0;
            for (final KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]> stream : streams) {
                this.readerService.submit(new KafkaConsumer(stream, threadNumber, msgProcessor));
                threadNumber++;
            }
        }


private static ConsumerConfig createConsumerConfig() {

        final Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("zookeeper.connect", "********");
        props.put("group.id", "testGrp");
        props.put("zookeeper.session.timeout.ms", 1000);
        props.put("zookeeper.sync.time.ms", 200);
        props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", 1000);
        props.put("auto.offset.reset", "smallest");
        props.put("consumer.timeout.ms", -1);
        props.put("fetch.message.max.bytes", 4194304);
        props.put("rebalance.backoff.ms", 1000);
        props.put("rebalance.max.retries", 1);

        return new ConsumerConfig(props);
    }
```

Comment: The Kafka version is 0.8.2

Comment: you should call run(final int threadsCount)  with 5 , if you run your application single instance. If you run 2 instances, call method with 3, one of the threads will be idle.

Comment: This is what I have told here. run(5) works fine. But run(4) is not working as the messages are there in the partition 5. It is supposed to work as per the doc.